# What are the example of apoc.cypher.doit?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am looking for some examples for `apoc.cypher.doit` use cases of all the parameters.

Comment: Please, give more context to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the docs - https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.doIt/

*(copying it here for reference)*

```
MATCH (node)
WITH node, labels(node)[0] AS label
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(
  "WITH $node AS node
   REMOVE node:" + label + "\n" +
  "SET node:" + apoc.text.capitalize(toLower(label)) + "\n" +
  "RETURN node",
  {node: node})
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

Comment: I just see a single use case scenario and I couldn't get much from it.. is there any other link for multiple scenarios.

Comment: Best to try it for your use case and see what issues you have and update the question accordingly. It is hard for us to understand what you intend to do with it. A real use case would be very useful